# Fatal error: Declaration of .. must be compatible with .. PHP

Tags: php, fatal-error

I'm getting the following error:

```
Fatal error: Declaration of Shoppingcart::addToCart() must be compatible with that of Ishoppingcart::addToCart() in klassen.php on line 118
```

What could be the problem? I can't find it
script:

```
<?php
// begin
interface Ishoppingcart{
    public function addToCart();
    public function printOverzicht();
}
abstract class Shoppingcart implements Ishoppingcart
{
    protected $producten = array();

    public function addToCart( Product $product) {
        $this->producten[] = $product;
    }
}
class Myshoppingcart extends Shoppingcart {
    public function printOverzicht(){
        echo ("<table border=1>
        <tr>
        <td colspan='7'>Bestellingoverzicht</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td bgcolor=#cccccc> Product ID</td>
        <td bgcolor=#cccccc> Beschrijving</td>
        <td bgcolor=#cccccc> Merk</td>
        <td bgcolor=#cccccc> Model</td>
        <td bgcolor=#cccccc> Prijs</td>
        <td bgcolor=#cccccc> Aantal</td>
        <td bgcolor=#cccccc> Korting</td>
        </tr>");

        foreach($this->producten as $product){
            $rij = "";
            $rij .= "<tr>";
            $rij .= "<td>".$product->getID()."</td>";
            $rij .= "<td>".$product->getBeschrijving()."</td>";
            $rij .= "<td>".$product->getMerk()."</td>";
            $rij .= "<td>".$product->getModel()."</td>";
            $rij .= "<td>".$product->getPrijs()."</td>";
            $rij .= "<td>".$product->getAantal()."</td>";
            $rij .= "<td>".$product->getKorting()."</td>";
            $rij .= "</tr>";
            echo ($rij);
        }
        echo ("</table>");
    }
}
class Product {
    private $id;
    private $beschrijving;
    private $merk;
    private $model;
    private $prijs;
    private $aantal;
    private $korting;

    function __construct($id,
                        $merk,
                        $model,
                        $prijs,
                        $aantal,
                        $korting){
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->beschrijving = $beschrijving;
        $this->merk = $merk;
        $this->model = $model;
        $this->prijs = $prijs;
        $this->aantal = $aantal;
        $this->korting = $korting;
        echo ("<br />Nieuw Product object $beschrijving wordt aangemaakt");
                        }
    public function __destruct(){
        // voer benodigde acties uit
        echo ("<br />Product object $this->beschrijving wordt verwijderd");
    }
    // set function
    public function setId($id){
        $this->id = $id;
    }
    public function setBeschrijving($beschrijving){
        $this->beschrijving = $beschrijving;
    }
    public function setMerk($merk){
        $this->merk = $merk;
    }
    public function setModel($model){
        $this->model = $model;
    }
    public function setPrijs($prijs){
        $this->prijs = $prijs;
    }
    public function setAantal($aantal){
        $this->aantal = $aantal;
    }
    public function setKorting($korting){
        $this->korting = $korting;
    }
    // get function
    public function getId(){
        return $this->id = $id;
    }
    public function getBeschrijving(){
        return $this->beschrijving;
    }
    public function getMerk(){
        return $this->merk;
    }
    public function getModel(){
        return $this->model;
    }
    public function getPrijs(){
        return $this->prijs;
    }
    public function getAantal(){
        return $this->aantal;
    }
    public function getKorting(){
        return $this->korting;
    }

    // printProductInfo
    public function printProductInfo(){
    $rij = "<tr><td>$this->id</td>";
    $rij .= "<td>$this->beschrijving</td>";
    $rij .= "<td>$this->merk</td>";
    $rij .= "<td>$this->model</td>";
    $rij .= "<td>$this->prijs</td>";
    $rij .= "<td>$this->aantal</td>";
    $rij .= "<td>$this->korting</td>";  
    echo ($rij);
    }
}
// einde
?>
```

Comment: In which exact version of PHP this error is coming. in PHP7.2 it was warning in php7.4 its fatal error.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

`Ishoppingcart::addToCart()` states that the method does not take any parameter, while the implementation `Shoppingcart::addToCart(Product $product)` requires that a parameter of type `Product` must be passed into the method. This means that both declarations are incompatible and while the implemented interface must be satisfied PHP throws the shown error.

Solution would be to either change `Ishoppingcart::addToCart()` to `Ishoppingcart::addToCart(Product $product)` so that it requires a parameter of type `Product` or to change `Shoppingcart::addToCart(Product $product)` to allow no parameter to passed into the method: `Shoppingcart::addToCart(Product $product = null)`;

The correct way depends on your application requirements.

Comment: @F4LLCON In my opinion, using the default value of NULL is a hack that defeats the purpose of an interface.  I expect an interface to have a contract of "this is *exactly* the signature of this method."  I feel that either the interface should have the parameter, or the two methods should be named differently.

Comment: I'm exactly following instructions in my book. But it did not work. I will use the hack for now because changing something will effect other things in the script.

Comment: @F4LLCON Wait that's from a book?  I would switch books.  It's not a big deal alone, but for an edited, published book, I would not expect such a mistake on the author's part.

Comment: I know, the course I'm following has a teacher that wrote this book. If I complain about something not working, he will say it's probably something you (I) are doing wrong. He will not help etc. But It's still one week and I'm done on this college and will go study Game Technology. I will burn this crappy book. ONLY problems, nothing worked. And the funny part is, the teacher who wrote this book, is saying we only are allowed to use this book. Going to send a complain to the school after I got my papers of graduation in my pocket. But anyways, thank you :)

Comment: Now that you're finished with the course, perhaps you'd like to share the book that was used as part of the curriculum, and maybe the college too? :)

Answer (score 8):

The declaration of a public function in a sub class must match that of its parent:

```
public function addToCart();
public function addToCart( Product $product)
```

You cannot add a parameter to the signature.

This is closely related to the [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

Answer (score 5):

Doesn't apply to this particular question, but if someone there is having this issue, make sure to include the return value if the Interface specifies it.

An interface with a function like this:

```
abstract public function crawled(Something $some): void;
```

needs to be implemented as:

```
public function crawled(Something $some): void {
}
```

In my case I was missing the `: void` return type.

Comment: I have the same problem with PHP 8. Funny enough my dev environment does not care about the `: void`, but production does care about it and it make a big problem. I reported and issue about it https://github.com/bugsnag/bugsnag-laravel/issues/491

Answer (score 1):

Interface Ishoppingcart seems to define addToShoppingCart without parameters, but class Shoppingcart defines the same function taking Product as a parameter. I suppose the method in the interface should take Product as a parameter as well.

Answer (score -1):

This can also happen if Intelephense sees multiple classes with the same name but with different signatures. They may not be in PHP's scope, but Intelephense allows specifying additional directories and seems to pick up backup directories and the like as well.