# Understanding Fatal error: Declaration of

Tags: php, zend-framework

What does this error mean? 
How should I understand it?

```
Fatal error: Declaration of Zend_Pdf_FileParserDataSource_File::__construct() must be compatible with Zend_Pdf_FileParserDataSource::__construct() in /www/htdocs/nether/http/123factuur/library/Zend/Pdf/FileParserDataSource/File.php on line 167
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fatal error: Declaration of .. must be compatible with .. PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11273313/fatal-error-declaration-of-must-be-compatible-with-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basing on http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/279601/ the issue is for Zend before version 1.11.12 for PHP 5.4. In the same article workarounds exist:

Make a copy of the lib/Zend/Pdf/FileParserDataSource.php file. Next, move the copy to app/code/local/Zend/Pdf/FileParserDataSource.php

Change

```
abstract public function __construct();
```

To

```
abstract public function __construct($filePath);
```