# PhalconRest\Http\Response::setJsonContent declaration fatal error

Tags: phalcon, php-7.2

Initially used PHP 7.1.1 and Phalcon 3.4 to support API end. Once upgraded the PHP 7.2.24 and Phalcon 4.0.0 we faced the Phalcon response issue when calling the API. We mainly used Phalcon-rest to support API.
Below attached the file structure, source code and issue what I faced. Please share your inputs to resolve the issue.

[image: File structure]

> **Fatal error**: Declaration of
>   PhalconRest\Http\Response::setJsonContent($content, $jsonOptions = 0,
>   $depth = 512) must be compatible with
>   Phalcon\Http\Response::setJsonContent($content, int $jsonOptions =
>   NULL, int $depth = NULL): Phalcon\Http\ResponseInterface in
>   **C:\dev\servicechum_api\vendor\redound\phalcon-rest\src\PhalconRest\Http\Response.php** on line **68**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fatal error: Declaration of .. must be compatible with .. PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11273313/fatal-error-declaration-of-must-be-compatible-with-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The upstream package you use (`redound/phalcon-rest`) is [incompatible with modern PHP versions](https://github.com/redound/phalcon-rest/issues/36). The error message is self explanatory: the implementation of the `Response::setJsonContent` method must match the parent, while it does not.

Judging by the code, lack of tests, invalid library constraints (vide `"php": ">=5.4"`) in the `composer.json` either downgrade your PHP or stop using this software, but prefer latter.