# Magento when enabling log through command line getting error

Tags: magento, magento2

In my Magento application when I try to enable logging in command line using below code

```
# bin/magento setup:config:set –enable-debug-logging=true
```

I am getting the error

```
PHP Fatal error:  Declaration of Magenest\SagePay\Helper\Logger::debug($message, array $context = []) must be compatible with Monolog\Logger::debug($message, array $context = []): void in /vendor/magenest/module-sage-pay-basic/Helper/Logger.php on line 49
```

Comment: can take a look on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11273313/fatal-error-declaration-of-must-be-compatible-with-php

Comment: and better to paste the code of related function into the question